# copy constructor for vector with objects

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

the default copy constructor of vector is defined as:

> (4) copy constructor (and copying with allocator)
>       Constructs a container with a copy of each of the elements in x, in the same order.

I got couple of questions about using this copy constructor.
I got this vector:

```
 std::vector<OrderPair> orderList;
```

where

```
typedef std::pair<int, Dish> OrderPair;
```

and Dish is simple class (without pointers)

```
enum DishType{
    VEG, SPC, BVG, ALC
};

class Dish{
private:
    const int id;
    const std::string name;
    const int price;
    const DishType type;
};
```

Assume A is a vector as described above with some elements,
which kind of copy I will get by doing:

```
std::vector<OrderPair> B=A;
```

in case the elements were created without new and in case they were created by new?
what about the case the some of the fields of Dish were pointers?

Thank you.

Comment: What is `DishType`?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie
@d
sorry, it's just enum
enum DishType{
    VEG, SPC, BVG, ALC
};

Comment: Well, I suggest you leave `Dish` as is.  Why would you want to change to pointers?

Comment: I don't want to. I just want to understand what kind of copy the copy constructor of vector do, and especially in the cases described above.
it's more for learning.

Comment: It would probably just use the default copy assignment operator since you didn't provide one

Comment: @Mr.OY The default copy constructor or assignment is invoked, and will do a shallow copy.  This topic is really discussed better in a good C++ book.

Comment: @stackptr, you mean it will make kind of shallow copy? so for the Dish class (which as no pointers) it should be fine?

Comment: @Mr.OY It will default to shallow copy unless you write your own

Comment: @Mr.OY -- The default copy and assignment functions will work fine.  That is what any code should strive for, and that is for types to have proper copy semantics with little to no extra work to do.